# Invalid CSS after ".color-": expected selector, was "("

Tags: reactjs, sass

I don't know how to fix this problem, when I try implent `@color` this error happens, someone can help me for this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try with correct syntax

```
$colors: ("black": #000, "foo": #333);
```

Comment: It still have error 
SassError: Invalid CSS after ".color-": expected selector, was '("black": #000, "fo'
        on line 25 of src/sasss/_base.scss

Comment: i don't know why  it still appear this

Comment: @LongNgo Can you try with some sass playgrounds like https://www.sassmeister.com/, to make sure the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

the correct syntax for this is by using

```
$colors:("black":"#000000","color2":#fff);
```

try to avoid first'(' and ending ')' .